# I am getting "java.util.zip.ZipException: unknown compression method" in my restassured code

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am getting this error "java.util.zip.ZipException: unknown compression method" however I am dealing with the API rest-assured. Could it be related to dependencies in the pom.xml?

I googled this issue and just have seen that it is about zip files but as you see there is no zip coding.

Here is my code and pom.xml:

```java
@Test
public void trelloCallTest() {
    String key = "mykey";
    String token = "mytoken";

    Response response = given()
        .spec(new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://api.trello.com/1").build())
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .log().all()
        .when()
        .queryParams("key", key,
            "token",
            token,
            "name", "myname")
        .post("/boards/");

    String jsonString = response.asString();
    System.out.println(jsonString);

    response.then().statusCode(200);
}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json- 
             simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: From your code you have `post("/boards/")` - I didn't find that post request is supported for boards in the way you try to perform that https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-boards/

Comment: Hello,this is whole request :https://api.trello.com/1/boards/?key=key&token=token&name="test_board"

Answer (score 0):

From your code you have `post("/boards/")` - I didn't find that post request is supported for boards in the way you try to perform that https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-boards/  The issue you face may be related to unexpected response type, e.g it may be GZIPPED

Answer (score 0):

Hi I edited these lines and worked:

```
 Response response = given().spec(new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://api.trello.com/1").setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .build())
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .queryParams("key", key,
                       "token",
                             token,
                             "name", "myname")
                .post("/boards/");
```